# How to debug an AJAX operation that is not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here is my html in sell.php

```
<form id="myForm" action="validSell.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Here is my_java.php

```
$("#submit").click( function() {

    $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
        $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
        function(info) {

        $("#ack").empty();
        $("#ack").html(info);
    });

    $("#myForm").submit(function() {
        return false;
    });
});
```

i have a php action file and echo works fine. But its suppose to appear in

`<div style="color:red;" id="ack"></div>` in the html page.

i have linked the javascript with this line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/my_java.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you receiving any javascript errors? What is happening when you click the button? Anything? Nothing?

Comment: Doing `$("#myForm").submit()` inside `$("#submit").click()` is redundant, as you only need one of these, not both.

Comment: Are we to assume that you have the jquery library loaded? Have you tried wrapping your code in a document ready? ie. `$(function(){ ... });`

Comment: And I don't see `<div style="color:red;" id="ack"></div>` in your provided code. Perhaps you could include all the relevant code to ensure everything is there, ie. jquery lib, `<div id="ack"</div>` etc.

Comment: actually, the question is saying that javascript code is a PHP file ? please improve your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
    $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
    function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

}).done(function(info) {
    $("#ack").empty().html(info);
});
```

Try this. You were in the thinking that `info` was passing back data from the call, but in fact, it was merely passing the `event` from the $.post